# Simulate airplane mode in iPhone Simulator

Tags: iphone, ios-simulator

Is there any way to simulate airplane mode in the iPhone Simulator?

Answer (score 144, accepted):

Turn off your network connection on the Mac.

Comment: It's harder than it sounds, though our team has asked Apple for similar functionality. The problem is that apps running in the simulator are really Mac apps. The iPhone Simulator doesn't emulate the iPhone; it's just an environment for Mac apps to link against and *look* like an iPhone. So you need a way, at the system layer, to restrict an app from talking to the network. Unix doesn't provide that; it would almost certainly need kernel support to get it. You could do it more easily for NSURLConnection and its kin, but it could be more confusing if some calls work and some don't.

Comment: This does not simulate airplane mode...as the GPS simulator still functions but does not return a value.

Comment: Just turning off your network connection is not so useful in some circumstances. For example, when you're testing reachability and internet availability -- sometimes you really do need airplane mode. The simulator not having a working networking connection isn't really the same. Also, some workplaces have computers that have real authentication problems that mean killing your network connection isn't always an option (as everything goes haywire).

Comment: If you are working with a web service hosted on your machine, it has no effect.

Comment: I agree with occuulus. When working in the office, turning off the network for the entire machine is severely detrimental to the communication in the work environment. There are many situations where this is not an acceptable solution.

Comment: When working with local(host) web services, the "trick" is to use your ip address - rather than `localhost` - on your services calls, whitelist the ip in config.xml if you use phonegap/cordova then kill your network connection.

Comment: This needs to change, surely Apple has the ability to turn off network connectivity on a per-app basis. I often have things running that need the system network to remain active (sometimes large TimeCapsule backups) - so turning off the network isn't an option - and it can take a while for a 100gb+ backup to finish.

Comment: Also, super hard to do this with Xamarin from Visual Studio since it needs the network connection to debug the app.

Comment: I don't believe restricting an app from talking to the network is not THAT hard. See all the apps mentioned.

Comment: What if I need to keep my mac connected while doing tests in "airplane" mode? How hard is to them to put a network switch inside the simulator?

Comment: What would happen to my youtube video then?

Comment: The very reason I want to simulate airplane mode is because I'm waiting for an email, and I didn't want to put my devices in airplane mode. Seems like an oversight on Apple's part.

Comment: None of the answers here is correct. Turning off the network to the desktop nor using a link conditioner,  both of which are likely to be highly problematic from an operational perspective, are equivalent to turning on airplane mode. It beggars belief that Apple, 13 years on from the original question, still has not implemented this capability into the sim.

Answer (score 65):

You could install Apple's Network Link Conditioner

On Yosemite:

> Network Link Conditioner can be found in the "Hardware IO Tools for Xcode" package. This can be downloaded from the [Apple Developer Downloads page](https://developer.apple.com/downloads/?q=Hardware%20IO%20Tools). Once the download has finished, open the DMG and double-click "Network Link Condition.prefPane" to install ([source](http://nshipster.com/network-link-conditioner/)).

With this preferences panel you could create a profile with 0kbps speed.

[image: Network Link Conditioner]

On older versions of OSX:

Mountain Lion / Mavericks: `Xcode > Open Developer Tool > More Developer Tools`
Lion: `/Developer/Applications/Utilities/Network Link Conditioner`

Comment: Reachability does not see any change when using Network Link Conditioner.  In fact, when I set it to 0kbps and 100% packet loss, it still reports everything as up and reachable through wifi.  This does not work for trying to test Airplane mode.

Comment: are you sure you switched the big switch on the left to "ON" ?

Comment: Same problem here, Link Conditioner to 0kbps up/down and 100% packet loss up/down doesn't help. The iOS Simulator just times out after a while. 0kbps is assumed as bandwidth MAX.

Comment: The problem is that it is similar to switching off the network connection. Its not very nice as all other apps you are using also lose Internet connection.

Answer (score 22):

You can use [Little Snitch](http://www.obdev.at/products/littlesnitch/index.html) too to temp. block the internet connection for this app.

Comment: so it means you can edit hosts files in order to achieve the same, thanks for the idea buddy.