# XCUITest - How to disable Wi Fi while app is running?

Tags: xcode, xcuitest

I want to automate how ios App behave while running the XCUITest. When manually executing the test, I turn off the wi fi adapter. How do I do that using Xcode UI test?

thanks

p.s. I found that we can use below command to disable wi fi. But to do this I will need to send my app to background. I need to do this without sending current app to background.

```
let settingsApp = XCUIApplication(bundleIdentifier: "com.apple.Preferences")

settingsApp.launch()

settingsApp.tables.cells["Airplane Mode"].tap()
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can re-activate your app afterwards with the new activate() method on XCUIApplication. It will resume your app without restarting it.

```
    let app = XCUIApplication()
    app.launch()

    let settingsApp = XCUIApplication(bundleIdentifier: "com.apple.Preferences")
    settingsApp.launch()
    settingsApp.tables.cells["Airplane Mode"].tap()

    // Relaunch app without restarting it
    app.activate()
```

Comment: Additionally, if you want to know if the airplane mode is current enabled before you go to Settings, try `let isAirplaneMode = XCUIApplication(bundleIdentifier: "com.apple.springboard").statusBars.images["Airplane mode on"]`

Comment: What's worth mentioning (as of 2022): Airplane mode is only available on real iOS/iPadOS devices, but not on simulators. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1614802/simulate-airplane-mode-in-iphone-simulator for more information.